# Create custom locator file - what license level of ArcDesktop do I need?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license

I would like to create custom locators in ArcDesktop to circumvent this problem:
[US One Address locator style missing city, state and zip code fields?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5786/why-doesnt-us-one-address-locator-style-have-city-state-or-zip-code-fields)

So I am going to buy a copy of ArcDesktop, but I think there are 3 levels, so I'm not sure which one to buy?  ArcView, ArcEditor or ArcInfo.

Which level allows you to create custom locators, aka .lot files?

Answer (score 5):

You can create **Composite Address Locators in ArcGIS** at all licence levels.

*"A composite address locator consists of two or more individual address locators and/or geocode services. When addresses are geocoded against the composite address locator, they are automatically matched against each of the individual address locators and services. The composite address locator stores only references to the participating address locators and geocode services; it does not contain the actual address information, indexes, and data of the individual locators.
Composite address locators can be created in any workspace, such as a geodatabase or file folder. Although it is not required that you save the composite address locator in the same workspace as the participating address locators, it is a good practice to do since managing and distributing composite address locators is easier."*

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_composite_address_locator/00250000003r000000/